In Unity, rotating one object around another object is like orbiting around in the scene editor by holding Alt and left-clicking
I've tried combining two RotateArounds and then reading mouse offsets, but it shakes violently when it reaches the top. I attempted to lock it at 90 degrees, but it still didn't work. I haven't found a good way to achieve it, as regular rotation also has gimbal lock issues.
I hope to achieve the orbit rotation similar to Alt + left-click in the Unity editor, and also to lock at 90 degrees at the top, rather than continuing the orbit rotation after reaching the top, which would cause the screen to be inverted.

Do you want to rotate an object around another object using mouse input? Or do you want to rotate the camera view? Based on what input do you want to rotate?

Just like Unity. the mouse of screen position

Sorry to bother you again but some more clarification is needed since your title and description are a little confusing. Do you want to have an object rotate around another object? Do you want to rotate the camera view around an object similar to Unity Editor scene view? If so, do you want to control this via your mouse input? Please specify your problem, then we can maybe help:)

Just like Unity. you can press mouse right button and alt to rotate around the point. But limit x between 90 to -90.

I think I got what you mean now. Let me know if the answer does what you expect. Otherwise please further clarify

it part of script, but this will achive it;
var delta = mPlayerInput.CameraCC.MouseDelta.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        if (delta == Vector2.zero) return;

        float x = mCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float y = mCamera.transform.eulerAngles.x;
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(Target.position, mCamera.transform.position);

        if (x > 180) x -= 360;
        if (y > 180) y -= 360;

        x += delta.x * xSpeed * 0.02f;
        y -= delta.y * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        Vector3 position = rotation * new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance) + Target.position;

        mCamera.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(position, rotation);


The following script, attached to your Camera object:

Rotates the camera around an object's Transform provided through the inspector based on mouse movement input
Clamps the rotation at the top and bottom

    using UnityEngine;

    public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Tooltip("Transform of an object about which's center point camera should rotate")]
        public Transform objToRotAbout;
        [Tooltip("Rotation speed. Multiplication factor for mouse movement delta")]
        public float rotationSpeed = 0.05f;
    
        [Tooltip("Position of mouse in last frame")]
        private Vector3 lastMousePos;
        [Tooltip("Pose of camera in last frame")]
        private Pose lastCamPose;
    
    
        void Update()
        {
            // On mouse button down initially
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                // Start with current mouse position
                lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            }
    
            // On mouse button pressed down continuously
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                // Rotate camera about object center
                RotateCamera();
            }
        }
    
        void RotateCamera()
        {
            // Calculate mouse movement delta & update last mouse position to current
            Vector3 mouseDelta = Input.mousePosition - lastMousePos;
            lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    
            // Calculate rotation amount based on mouse movement delta
            float mouseX = mouseDelta.x * rotationSpeed;
            float mouseY = mouseDelta.y * rotationSpeed;
    
            // Store previous camera pose
            lastCamPose = new Pose(transform.position, transform.rotation);
    
            // Rotate camera about object
            transform.RotateAround(objToRotAbout.position, Vector3.up, mouseX);
            transform.RotateAround(objToRotAbout.position, transform.right, -mouseY);
    
            // If camera upside down -> Revert to previous rotation
            if (Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down) > 0)
            {
                transform.SetPositionAndRotation(lastCamPose.position, lastCamPose.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

Currently, it resets the cameras pose if it detects that it is upside down. Instead, you could also rotate a placeholder first, check if it overrotates, and update the camera's pose only if conditions are fulfilled. But it does work in this form as well.

thanks, but if the camera rotation.z change it will can`t move. I write one.
